# Hadoop on RHEL Start-dfs.sh Strange Behavior

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set up Hadoop on a RHEL in Pseudo-Distributed mode. Everything seems working fine except that every time I start HDFS by using start-dfs.sh, the command window hang at

```
"Starting namenode, ...".
```

So, I have to use "control + c" to end this command and it then continues to

```
"localhost: starting secondarynamenode, ..." and 
"localhost: starting datanode,...".
```

It just runs line by line and I have to use the "enter" key to keep it run the next command. But once it's done, the system seems to work fine. And this happens to all the other script in the bin folder such as stop-dfs.sh. So, I would assume this is related to RHEL and scripting?

Can anybody tell me how to fix this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you find anything strange in the logs?

Comment: I found out why. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why, the default shell for the RHEL I am using is csh. And I have put an automatic script to change it to bash at login. Somehow it conflicts with the line "#!/usr/bin/env bash". Once I commented out the automatic bash switch, it worked fine.

Comment: Cool. Glad that you got it working. Mark it so that others can benefit from it :)

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks a lot for your attention. I will mark it once the system allows me to.